# AngularJS: Can a Promise "call" another function?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a controller which calls **getCurrentUser** from a service and **if** a record is returned, adds the necessary additional information to the $scope. If no record is found, this is a new user and I have to get additional information before he/she can continue. I have a **getLoggedInUser** function to compute all of the variables I can for the new user from SharePoint's user model and then I present a form for the rest.

My question is can I only call getLoggedInUser **IF** there is no record found or do I have to call both everytime (and put variables not needed in the $scope) so that I have access to it when I need it?

This is how I have it now -- calling the getLoggedInUser first to have the info available if I return no records. It just doesn't seem like this is proper because most of the time I won't need that extra computing since most users will already exists.

I am just learning AngularJS so I appreciate your help.

```
(function(){

    var MainController = function($scope, SharePointJSOMService){
        $scope.current_user = [];
        $scope.loggedInUser = [];

        SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(runMyCode, "SP.js");

        function runMyCode(){
            $scope.spReady = _spPageContextInfo;

            $.when(SharePointJSOMService.getLoggedInUser())
                .done(function(jsonObject){
                    $scope.loggedInUser = jsonObject.d;

                    $scope.UserName = $scope.loggedInUser.LoginName;
                    $scope.Display_Name_Full = $scope.loggedInUser.Title;
                    $scope.Display_Name = $scope.Display_Name_Full.substring(0, $scope.Display_Name_Full.indexOf('(')-1);
                    $scope.Email_365 = $scope.loggedInUser.Email;
                    $scope.Email_Company = $scope.UserName.substring($scope.UserName.lastIndexOf('|')+1);
                    $scope.FName = $scope.Email_Company.substring(0, $scope.Email_Company.indexOf('.'));
                    $scope.LName = $scope.Email_Company.substring($scope.Email_Company.indexOf('.')+1, $scope.Email_Company.indexOf('@'));
                    $scope.$apply();
                })
                .fail(function(err){
                    $scope.prefs = true;
                    console.info(JSON.stringify(err)); 
                });

            $.when(SharePointJSOMService.getCurrentUser())
                .done(function(jsonObject){
                    if(jsonObject.d.results.length < 1){
                        // new user
                        $scope.prefs = true; // force preference pane
                        $scope.current_user = {};
                        $scope.projectClose = 'true';
                        $scope.taskClose = 'true';
                        $scope.projectManagerClose = 'true';
                        $scope.$apply();
                    } else {
                        // existing user
                        $scope.prefs = false;
                        $scope.current_user = jsonObject.d.results[0];
                        switch($scope.current_user.User_Role){
                            case 'USR':
                                $scope.project_view = 'all_cs_proj';
                                $scope.projectClose = 'true';
                                break;
                            case 'RSC':
                                $scope.project_view = 'all_it_proj';
                                $scope.projectClose = 'true';
                                break;
                            case 'RQC':
                                $scope.project_view = 'my_rc_proj';
                                $scope.projectClose = 'true';
                                break;
                            case 'PMG':
                                $scope.project_view = 'my_pm_proj';
                                $scope.projectClose = 'true';
                                break;
                            case 'ADM':
                                $scope.project_view = 'my_amm_proj';
                                $scope.projectClose = 'true';
                                break;
                            default:
                                $scope.project_view = 'my_cs_proj';
                                $scope.projectClose = 'false';
                                break;
                        } // end switch
                        $scope.$apply();
                    } // end if
               })
               .fail(function(err){
                $scope.prefs = true;
                console.info(JSON.stringify(err)); 

        });
    }; // end MainController

    MainController.$inject = ['$scope', 'SharePointJSOMService'];

    angular.module('appITI').controller('MainController', MainController);
})();
```

Comment: Why not wrap this in a service method and return a promise. We use something like that when accessing data that can be already cached in memory, we return the same promise, but depending if the data is in cache we resolve the promise using the cached value or the service call result. In your case the service would just check if the user exists if not, resolve the promise using the empty structure.

Comment: Isn't it already a service method ... it is calling two methods in the SharePointJSOMService

Comment: If you want to call getCurrentUser and if no results then call getLoggedInUser you could make that call inside the .getCurrentUser done callback. Would that make sense for you scenario?

Comment: @Braulio THAT's what I am wanting to do but I don't know the syntax of the done callback. Can I use "var = XXX" INSIDE a .done? to keep all the other data inside loggedInUser out of the $scope (I really only need LoginName and Title since everything else is calculated)? I am so new to AngularJS, I just don't know HOW to make that callback inside .getCurrentUser .done. And, THANKS for taking the time, I know some people hate newbie questions but it is how we learn.

Comment: @Braulio, PLEASE help inside an answer so I can mark it when we are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure what you are looking for but see if this fits.  Just make another service call from inside the callback function.

I got rid of all of 'apply' because I don't think they are needed but you may have to put some back in. HTH.

```
function(){

var MainController = function($scope, SharePointJSOMService){
    $scope.current_user = [];
    $scope.loggedInUser = [];

    SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(runMyCode, "SP.js");

    function runMyCode(){
        $scope.spReady = _spPageContextInfo;

        $.when(SharePointJSOMService.getCurrentUser())
            .done(function(jsonObject){
                if(jsonObject.d.results.length < 1){
                    // new user
                    $.when(SharePointJSOMService.getLoggedInUser())
                       .done(function(jsonObject){
                        $scope.loggedInUser = jsonObject.d;

                        $scope.UserName = $scope.loggedInUser.LoginName;
                        $scope.Display_Name_Full = $scope.loggedInUser.Title;
                        $scope.Display_Name = $scope.Display_Name_Full.substring(0, $scope.Display_Name_Full.indexOf('(')-1);
                        $scope.Email_365 = $scope.loggedInUser.Email;
                        $scope.Email_Company =       $scope.UserName.substring($scope.UserName.lastIndexOf('|')+1);
                        $scope.FName = $scope.Email_Company.substring(0, $scope.Email_Company.indexOf('.'));
                        $scope.LName = $scope.Email_Company.substring($scope.Email_Company.indexOf('.')+1, $scope.Email_Company.indexOf('@'));

                        $scope.prefs = true; // force preference pane
                        $scope.current_user = {};
                        $scope.projectClose = 'true';
                        $scope.taskClose = 'true';
                        $scope.projectManagerClose = 'true';
                      })
                      .fail(function(err){
                        $scope.prefs = true;
                        console.info(JSON.stringify(err)); 
                      });       
                } else {
                    // existing user
                    $scope.prefs = false;
                    $scope.current_user = jsonObject.d.results[0];
                    switch($scope.current_user.User_Role){
                        case 'USR':
                            $scope.project_view = 'all_cs_proj';
                            $scope.projectClose = 'true';
                            break;
                        case 'RSC':
                            $scope.project_view = 'all_it_proj';
                            $scope.projectClose = 'true';
                            break;
                        case 'RQC':
                            $scope.project_view = 'my_rc_proj';
                            $scope.projectClose = 'true';
                            break;
                        case 'PMG':
                            $scope.project_view = 'my_pm_proj';
                            $scope.projectClose = 'true';
                            break;
                        case 'ADM':
                            $scope.project_view = 'my_amm_proj';
                            $scope.projectClose = 'true';
                            break;
                        default:
                            $scope.project_view = 'my_cs_proj';
                            $scope.projectClose = 'false';
                            break;
                    } // end switch
                } // end if
           })
           .fail(function(err){
            $scope.prefs = true;
            console.info(JSON.stringify(err)); 

    });
}; // end MainController

MainController.$inject = ['$scope', 'SharePointJSOMService'];

angular.module('appITI').controller('MainController', MainController);
})();
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for (I hope I know enough about NG to mean that is the right solution ... LOL). I didn't know you could just add a $.when as a callback so that's what I learned today. Thanks!!!